# Why doesn’t assigning an int to an f32 variable compile?

Tags: casting, rust

Why does rust consider assigning an int value to a float variable as an error even though there is no narrowing of value?

```
fn main() {
   let i: f32 = 1i;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Rust, all such casting must be done explicitly:

```
fn main() {
    let i = 1i as f32;
}
```

This is a simple design decision.

Also the conversion from `int` to `f32` is not lossless, still more reason for needing such things to be explicit.

Comment: My question would have made sense if an i8 were assigned to a f32 variable. Anyways thank you for the explanation.